# Get notified when a JMS message is consumed

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way to get notified when a JMS Message is consumed from a JMS queue? Like a listener or notification?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using ActiveMQ since you tagged the question with it.

You can register for an **advisory** notification when a message is consumed by a client. See the [docs for advisories](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) and the one you're looking for is **ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue**.

**===== Update =====**

Oh, errr..  you're using Joram, not ActiveMQ. It's not as simple, but you could use a [client side interceptor](http://joram.ow2.org/current/javadoc/org/objectweb/joram/client/jms/MessageInterceptor.html) which will return an acknowledgement message back to a queue or a topic which you would then listen on. The interface looks like this:

```
public interface MessageInterceptor {
    public void handle(javax.jms.Message pMessage, javax.jms.Session pSession);
}
```

See chapter 3.5. Message interceptors of the latest [Joram doc PDF](http://joram.ow2.org/doc/Joram-en.pdf).

You could also use a **interceptor_out** server side interceptor.

Comment: Thank for your reply but unfortunately i'm not using ActiveMQ but OW2 JORAM. I tagged ActiveMQ it because i'm interested in learning how it works with other MQs.

Answer (score 1):

No the JMS API doesnt provide any way to message delivery notification options. This will have to be done at the application level.